# Facebook connect button of a drupal site doesn't work inside canvas app

Tags: javascript, facebook, drupal, facebook-graph-api

I am building this drupal website which i want to include it inside a facebook canvas...

The problem is that it's functional outside facebook but not inside it.

here's the app canvas...

http://www.facebook.com/pages/Was-penelope/475770399104342?sk=app_346824075388300

Can you please tell me, how can this happen?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re trying to display the OAuth dialog within your iframe, which you can’t. (My browser [opera] shows an error saying that this page is not allowed to be displayed in an iframe.)

Just use `FB.login` to log your users in.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, which fb.login do i have to use?
And please what do you mean i'm using the OAuth dialog within my iframe?

Comment: _“which fb.login do i have to use?”_ – the only one there is: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/ – _“And please what do you mean i'm using the OAuth dialog within my iframe?”_ – exactly that, you are trying to link to the Oauth dialog from your login button, but since that link get’s opened within the iframe, it does not work.

Comment: Thanks, but one last question, can i create a fb login button and integrate it in a drupal module? because what i do is that i create a drupal account for users who do connect...

Comment: Of course you can. Just have them login resp. connect to your app, get the necessary info you need to create an account for them – and then create a new account with that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is not functional, or may be you already found a solution, but I can see the site when I navigate to that link.

Comment: In fact i just changed some things, you can see the website but you can't use the facebook connect button... it doesn't work...